# PHP processing form returns NULL for checkbox and radio buttons and does not display text area field

Tags: php, checkbox

I am new to php, and would GREATLY appreciate any help anyone can give me with this! Here is an example of my checkbox code:

```
     <legend>Fiction of Interest</legend>
    <p class="group">Please check the literary genres that are of interest to you:</p>
    <ul class="formList">
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fictioninterest[]" value="literaryfiction"  id="lfitem" 
    <?php if ((isset($fictioninterest)) && (in_array("literaryfiction", $fictioninterest))) { echo "checked"; } ?> />
     <label for="in">Literary Fiction</label>
```

Here is an example of my radio button code:

```
    <legend>Connecting with the Author</legend>
    <p class="group">Would you like to coincide your Book Club event with the author's BlogTalk radio interview?</p>
    <p class="group">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="blogtalk" value="yes" id="yesitem" <?php if ((isset($blogtalk)) && ($blogtalk==='yes')) { echo "checked"; } ?> />
    <label for="yesitem">Yes</label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="blogtalk" value="no" id="noitem" <?php if ((isset($blogtalk)) && ($blogtalk==='no')) { echo "checked"; } ?> />
    <label for="noitem">Not at this time</label>
    </p>
```

And here is my text area code:

```
    <p class="group">
      <label for="comments" class="text">Additional comments</label>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments">
      <?php if (isset($comments)) { echo $comments; } ?></textarea>
    </p>
```

I would SO appreciate any help with this! Thank you so much!

I am sorry - as I said I am trying to teach myself php and am still getting my head around even the basics. When my form is processed and it sends the results to an email, the checkboxes come back registering 'null' even though I have selected several. The radio buttons also come back 'null'. And no content is transmitted from my text area section to the email. I am sorry for not explaining properly, and again so appreciate your help!

```
<?php 
require_once("included_functions.php");
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['action']))):

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$formerrors = false;

if ($name === '') :
    $err_name = '<div class="error">Sorry, your name is a required field</div>';
endif; // input field empty

if ($email === '') :
    $err_email = '<div class="error">Sorry, your email is a required field</div>';
endif; // input field empty

if (isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        $comments = filter_var($_POST['comments'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ); 
}

$formdata = array (
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'fictioninterest' => $fictioninterest,
    'bookclub' => $bookclub,
    'newsletter' => $newsletter,
    'blogtalk' => $blogtalk,
    'skype' => $skype
```

);

```
if (!($formerrors)) :
    $to             =   "bookclub@literaryfictionreview.com";
    $subject    =       "From $name -- Signup Page";
    $message    =       json_encode($formdata);

    $replyto    =       "From: bookclub@literaryfictionreview.com \r\n".
                        "Reply-To: bookclub@literaryfictionreview.com \r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message)):
        $msg = "";
    redirect_to("confirmation.html");
    else:
        $msg = "Problem sending the message";
    endif; // mail form data

endif; // check for form errors

endif; //form submitted
 ?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Since you don't show any of your actual php processing code, we can't really help you.

Comment: Hint: count the amount closing/opening parenthesis.

Comment: what does `var_dump($fictioninterest);` print? (Put it at the beginning, before calling `isset($fictioninterest)`)

Comment: I have added my php processing code above, and explained my problem more clearly - thanks so much for trying to help me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem might be that variables like `$fictoninterest` aren't defined. You only declared `$name` and `$email`. So you might just add something like

```
$fictioninterest = $_REQUEST['fictioninterest'];
```

to your code - of course you have to do this for all input fields you want to work with (`$comments`, `$blogtalk`, etc). Oh, and you might use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Joel! That worked exactly for all but the comments text area section, which in the php processing section I added in:   $comments = $_POST['comments'];    But the comment section did not manifest in the resultant email. I did exactly what I had done for the other sections, does a text area require anything different?

Comment: Just not sure how to make the text area section manifest from the form into the email?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. The comments don't appear in the mail because you probably forgot to add `'comments' => $comments,` to your $formdata-array.

Comment: You are exactly right! Thanks so much Joel for your help! I am utterly new to php and you have been a wonder - I SO appreciate it, thank you!